# How to detect when a JButton is pressed (swing)?

Tags: java, swing

In Java's swing package, I was wondering how to detect when a JButton is pressed.  Is there a function that is called when the button is pressed?  Thanks

Comment: have you tried reading on eventhandlers?

Comment: Take a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Possible of duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505279/test-if-a-javax-swing-jbutton-is-pressed-down

Comment: Do you really mean pressed, or do you mean pressed and released (which most people would refer to as clicked)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you deal with button pressing, you want to add what is known as an action listener. First, you must

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

then you can do the following

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // this makes sure the button you are pressing is the button variable
             if(e.getSource() == button) {
                // do action necessary code 
              }
       }
 });
```

Comment: `e.getSource() == button` is not necessary in this case

Comment: Not the down voter, but it could possibly be that the question is so simple and lacks any kind of effort by the poster, that people feel that it simple should be answered, or that it shouldn't provide a spoon feed answer. Also, `e.getSource() == button` isn't always the best choice for comparing the source of the event, as you may not have access to the code that registered the listener, instead you should be using `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` or better still, the [Action API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: Well i've never learned the ActionEvent#getActionCommand way of doing that, I've always done getting the source of the object